# Yii get url part from controller

Tags: controller, yii, url-rewriting, slug

I have **URL rule** like this:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(
        '' => 'site/index',
        '<controller:pages>/<slug>' => '<controller>/inPage',
    ),
    'showScriptName'=>false,
),
```

In action I can get slug like argument

```
public function actionInPage($slug)
{
    echo$slug;
}
```

But how can I get that parameter from main controller (*protected/components/controller.php*) or in *controller view*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way framework recommended.

```
Yii::app()->request->getParam('slug');
```

Answer (score 1):

In view you can pass the $slug, as param from your controller..

By the way in both Controller, and the view you should be able to access the slug by `$_GET['slug']`..